# How to show message Cash drawer is open and close that msg when cash drawer close, USB enabled?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have APG USB enable cash drawer. I am able to open then cash drawer and find out status of cash drawer if its open or close.

I made deligate when cash drawer get open  that fuction get fire. and open new form

```
splashform frm = new splashform();
frm.showdialog();
```

and when drawer get close it need to trigger function to `frm.close()`, due to ui contol goes to splash then fuction that is on parent form dot get fire and splash screen keep open.

How to solve this problem? To display msg on screen when drawer open nd keep display untill cash drawer get close.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to answer your question because your are showing just to little code but anyway I give it a guess.

This stackoverflow question shows some code how to work with a APG USB cash drawer. [Not able to open cashdrawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065679/not-able-to-open-cashdrawer) 
So I assume this drawer is yours or respectively the api works the same since you did not post any details. This addresses a different issue but shows some details on the api.

With the following line of code you can assign a callback on state change of the drawer.

```
cashDrawer.AssignCallback(StatusUpdate, true);
```

this triggers the callback

```
public void StatusUpdate(int status)
```

status 0 is close status 1 equals open. So the callback would be the place depending on your desired behavior to execute `frm.close()`

This is just a guess from the top of my head since you are not showing much code but I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @silverfighter Thanks for the answer and sorry for little detail. I am doing exactly as you said. I have read the mentioned question and used the same code. but problem is that on the status 1(open) I am opening new form which shows a message that cash drawer is open and close to continue. When I close drawer then get a call back with 0 status and trying to close that from. Problem is that if I do not open new form (message form) then I  call back trigger get fire. But if I open new form on open cash drawer then when I close, call back trigger do not get fire.

Comment: is the callback not triggered (breakpoint, Console.Writeln) or is there an issue with the form close? Any chance to get more details?

Comment: call back not triggered because when we open new form then it gets stop there to get close that form first and focus goes to that new form. If I write all that code to open new form into separate task and start that task on open cash drawer event then it work  but not able to keep new form infont so that user not able to use POS

Comment: Actully what i want is: When user open carh drawer then there should be one message on pos that cash drawer is open and user can not use pos. and when user close cash drawer then this message will get close automatic. I have all trigger and that works when drawer open and close . I do not know how to show that message , with form or picture box or what